# Show modal after clicking on a photo taken from external API

Tags: jquery, api, modal-dialog

I've created a page that searches for photos in the unsplash.com database using its API. What I want to do now is to create a modal that will appear after clicking on a specific photo showing its description, author and higher resolution version of itself.
How can I make it happen? 
I know how to make a modal in general but I don't know to attach it to the content taken from the external API.
The part of code that contains the search:

```
$(document).ready(function () {



  $(".searchButton").click(function () {
    event.preventDefault()

    var searchQuery = $(".inputField").val();
    var client_id = "FfYp1ZB8b1n8B14J8FDCBqGL8RxKFNOHi1JmHU-WBWI"

    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos',
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'GET',
      data: { query: searchQuery, client_id: client_id, per_page: 40 },

      success: function (data) {

        $(".foundPhotos").empty();

        data.results.forEach(photo => {
          $('.foundPhotos').append(` 
          <img class="image" title="Author:${photo.user.name} | ${photo.alt_description}" src="${photo.urls.small}"/>    
          `)
        });
      }
    })
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a pseudo code..

example..  add call function on image

```
<img src='./xyz.jpg' onlclick='show_photo_data('image_id_of_unsplash')'>
```

Now create a method which will accept the unplash image id so that you can get the details of the same image
once you get the response from unplash with description, author and higher. you can add the whole data using .html jquery method..

Example in Modal :

```
<div class='modal-body'>
<div id='image_disc'></div>
<div id='image_author'></div>
</div>
```

IN jquery

```
success: function (data) {
$(#image_author).html(photo.user.name});
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys, your answers helped me to move one step forward but I'm stuck again.
I was able to create a modal but it shows all photos inside and not only the one that was clicked and the modal is shown at  the bottom and not over the page. How can I solve it?
I would also like to add autocomplete to the search field and make it possible to move to other page of the search results (it shows only 30 photos and nothing else).
It's the code: https://codepen.io/mazarzycki/pen/abdzyXg

Comment: as i can see ur using some bootstrap element, is that true?

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code for you. It loading the image and the data you need in the modal.

Working Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/usmanmunir/y8tsg5dc/36/

HTML

```
<button class="searchButton">Search</button>

<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-background"></div>
  <div class="modal-card">
    <section class="modal-card-body">

            <div id="name"></div>
                        <div id="description"></div>
      <img id="haha" width="200px" height="200" alt=""/>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $(".searchButton").click(function () {
    event.preventDefault()

    var searchQuery = 'eyFKAj8LwKg';
    var client_id = "FfYp1ZB8b1n8B14J8FDCBqGL8RxKFNOHi1JmHU-WBWI"

    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://api.unsplash.com/photos/random',
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'GET',
      data: { client_id: client_id, per_page: 40 },
      success: function (data) {
        $('.modal').addClass('is-active')
        $('#name').html('Author: '+data.user.first_name+' '+data.user.last_name)
        $('#description').html('Description: '+data.alt_description)
        $("#haha").attr("src", data.urls.small);
      }
    })
  });
});
```